# AngularJS testing with Protractor- how to use regular expressions inside 'expect'

Tags: angularjs, regex, protractor

I have a few test cases that I have written up using the Protractor framework to test my angular JS app.

In a couple of the tests, I am expecting the browser to navigate to a particular page by clicking a button/ link. The issue that I'm having, is that the URL for the page that the button/ link redirect the user to is generated automatically, and will be different every time the user logs into the system.

I am trying to use a regular expression within the `expect` clause of my test, to ensure that the URL of the page that the button/ link redirects the test script to at least has the pattern that I am expecting. For example:

```
it('should navigate to the custom page', function() {
    browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);
    browser.actions().mouseMove(customPageBtn).perform();
    customPageBtn.click().then(function(){
        expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).toMatch(urlRegExpPattern);
    });
})
```

An example of the format that the actual URL of the page is would be:

> http://mySite/#/userpages/49f93853-b5df-4f11-bc81-d69b6a97cfde

and I have set the `urlRegExpPattern` variable as:

```
    var urlRegExpPattern = "^[a-zA-Z0-9]+?-+[a-zA-Z0-9]+?-+[a-zA-Z0-9]+?-+[a-zA-Z0-9]+?-+[a-zA-Z0-9]$";
```

But when I run this test at the moment, I get a failure message that says:

> Expected 'http://mysite/#/config/platform/49f93853-b5df-4f11-bc81-d69b6a97cfde' to match 'http://sysite/#/config/platform/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+?-+[a-zA-Z0-9]+?-+[a-zA-Z0-9]+?-+[a-zA-Z0-9]+?-+[a-zA-Z0-9]$'.

i.e. it appear that the `expect` clause is expecting the URL to match the exact characters of the regular expression- not any characters that could be represented by that regular expression.

How can I ensure that my `expect` clause will interpret the regular expression as a regular expression, and not as a string?

**Edit**

So, using the link that @Gunderson provided in their comment, I managed to get my regular expression matching correctly with:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9]{8}-[a-zA-Z0-9]{4}-[a-zA-Z0-9]{4}-[a-zA-Z0-9]{4}-[a-zA-Z0-9]{12}$
```

for a string in the format:

```
49f93853-b5df-4f11-bc81-d69b6a97cfde
```

Using this, I changed regular expression variables to:

```
var urlRegExp = /^[a-zA-Z0-9]{8}-[a-zA-Z0-9]{4}-[a-zA-Z0-9]{4}-[a-zA-Z0-9]{4}-[a-zA-Z0-9]{12}$/;
var configSystemUrlRegExpPattern = "http://mysite/#/config/system" + urlRegExp;
var configPlatformUrlRegExpPattern = "http://mysite/#/config/platform" + urlRegExp;
```

and updated my test case to:

```
it('should navigate to the Config System page', function() {
    console.log("Start Config System page test");
    browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);
    browser.actions().mouseMove(configMenuBtn).perform();
    pageConfigSystemBtn.click().then(function(){
        console.log("End Config System page test (then call)");
        expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).toMatch(configSystemUrlRegExpPattern);
    });
    console.log("End Config System page test");

})
```

But when I run my test, I still get a failure because:

> App should navigate to the Config System page
>     Message:
>       Expected 'http://mysite/#/config/system/67a4299c-d559-4e54-94df-b346e75b2ce7' to match 'http://mysite/#/config/system/^[a-zA-Z0-9]{8}-[a-zA-Z0-9]{4}-[a-zA-Z0-9]{4}-[a-zA-Z0-9]{4}-[a-zA-Z0-9]{12}$'.

i.e. it appears that my `expect` clause still doesn't think that the URL matches the pattern. Can anyone explain to me why this is?

Comment: Did you check the regex itself?  According to [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/BymR6H/2) that expression does not match your URL at all

Comment: and you should read up on regex usage, "a regular expression literal, which consists of a pattern enclosed between slashes, as follows: `var re = /ab+c/;`" https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

Comment: Thanks for that link @Gunderson - I managed to get the regular expression matching the URL pattern- and am now using that in my `expect` clause, but the test still appears to be failing because the URL doesn't match the pattern. Any ides why this is?